# Magento 2.2.6 Shipping method price tax calculation

Tags: magento2, shipping-tax

We have a problem with the shown price of the shipping methods at checkout.

I have tax rules setup for the netherlands 21% all other country don't have any tax rules.

We use the following settings:

- Tax class for shipping: Taxable goods
- Calculation settings > Shipping prices: Excluding tax
- Price Display Settings > Display Shipping Prices: Including tax
- Flat rate > Price : 1.50

When on the checkout page I choose county The Netherlands the price at the shipping methods shows 1.5 where it should show 1.82

When I change the settings to:

- Calculation settings > Shipping prices: Including tax
- Price Display Settings > Display Shipping Prices: Including tax

When on the checkout page I choose county The Netherlands the price at the shipping methods shows 1.50 and that is correct. But when I choose another country with no tax rules the shipping method stills shows 1.5 but this time it should be 1.24.

In the Order Summary block the price is always correct.

I checked the core file module-tax\view\frontend\web\template\checkout\shipping_method. Here you can see: method.price_incl_tax and method.price_excl_tax. these values are somehow always the same.

We tested on a magento 2.2.4 and there the problem does not exsist.
Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: i am facing same problem